# vim: How to search/replace in all opened files?

Tags: list, search, vim, replace, buffer

If I use :vimgrep, it searches all files under current directory. But my requirement is to search/replace among all opened files.

E.g. I'm using vim to open 3 files at the same time

```
vim 1.cpp 2.cpp 3.cpp
```

I wish to:

> 1. search all functions called "main" and display in quickfix window, among all 3 files.
> 2. Replace all "hello" with "world" in all 3 files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the command :

```
bufdo s/string/replacement/g
```

bufdo : action on all buffers . 
s : replacing 
g : globally .

Comment: Won't work on my side. You must use the "%" sign before the "s" (eg `bufdo %s/baseString/updatedString/g` ) to search the occurences through all the lines of all the buffers / files.

Answer (score 6):

If your Vim is recent enough you can use the `:cdo` command:

```
:vimgrep main {1,2,3}.cpp
:cwindow
:cdo s/foo/bar/g
```

Comment: you need to add " | update" to save each buffer, if it was changed. Because by default, Vim will not switch away from a buffer if it has been changed.

Comment: This solution needs to write the file names that `vimgrep` is to act upon and vimgrep does not seem to populate the quick fix windows for hidden buffers

Answer (score 3):

According to the way you work with multiple files in vim (tabs, windows, etc), you can [search and replace in multiple files](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_multiple_buffers) by using different command:

- `:tabdo` (all tabs)
- `:windo` (all windows in the current tab)
- `:bufdo` (all buffers, i.e. all those listed with the `:ls` command)
- `:argdo` (all files in argument list)
- `:cdo` (all files listed in the quickfix list)

First open multiple files with vim tab pages:

```bash
$ vim -p file1.txt file2.txt
```

then in the vim, you can search and replace in multiple files by using:

```
:tabdo %s/pattern/replace/gc
```

Comment: `:windo` is the only one that seemed to work for me, very awesome, i had 5 files open, worked like a charm, this is really something i've needed for years, finally had the situation to look it up.  thanks much!  also easier to remember because you can use the `%` in front still.  (I use `/gc` instead of just `/g` especially in this case.

Answer (score 2):

i have used the following command which works for me. use this command sequential.

`:set autowriteall`
`:bufdo! %s/pattern/replace/g`

Answer (score -3):

You can use the command mode.
%s/(findstring)/(replacestring)

Comment: That will replace in one file only. The question is about replacing strings in all open files at the same time.